# How do I in MySQL create a Select statement that looks into Two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in the MySql database which I need to select a single piece of data from.

```
CREATE TABLE `imagestoassess` (
    `idImagesToAssess` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `U` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
    `UHash` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `AddedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
    `AddedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ReportedCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ToAssess` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
     PRIMARY KEY (`idImagesToAssess`),
     UNIQUE KEY `UHash_UNIQUE` (`UHash`),
     KEY `IndexHash` (`UHash`),
     KEY `IndexCount` (`ReportedCount`),
     KEY `IndexToAssess` (`ToAssess`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=245581 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this table

```
CREATE TABLE `userarcx` (
    `idUserARCX` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `LinkId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `A` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `R` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `C` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `X` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ToAssess` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `AssessedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `AssessmentTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`idUserARCX`),
     UNIQUE KEY `idUserARCX_UNIQUE` (`idUserARCX`),
     UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`UserId`,`LinkId`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now what I want to do but I am no MySql coder is get the imagestoassess.U from imagestoassess where the userarcx.linkId != imagestoassess.idImagesToAssess for the userarcx.UserId supplied as a parameter.

So to elaborate a little. 
  imagestoassess is a list of urls of online images.
  UserARCX is a list of Images that have been taken from imagestoassess and processed by a user.
to get the next image from imagestoassess we need to make sure the user has not already processed that image before returning the next url (imagestoassess.U) to the user.

So can anyone explain how I should do this, please?

**Edit One:**
So I have an image link called dosy.png in imagestoassess I need to see if the User with an Id of 1 has processed that image in userarcx. If they haven't then I need to get the next image from imagestoassess and test that against the user id of 1 in userarcx. I continue to do that until I get an image the user has not processed and return that url.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add `INSERT` statements for sample data and the results you want to get with that sample data as tabular text.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are given a user and you want to list the images the user hasn't processed yet? Are you given the user id to start?

Comment: Yes I have all the information I need to get the result I just don't know how to write the sql to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for trying. In the end I decided to use a new table which held the last linkId that the user processed. That way the select statement would end "... WHERE linkId>LinkId;";

It is working now.